# Showing Text on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, text

I was wondering if there is a way to embed some text on Google Maps. I searched the [JS API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ImageMapType) and came up with some ideas, but I wasn't really satisfied with them.

The situation is that I draw some polygons on the map, and I want to show some numbers in that polygon. I implemented it with infoWindows now, but I want the numbers embedded into the map. It might have something to do with [MVCObject](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCObject) or [OverlayView](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverlayView), but I wasn't able to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Williams made a library that should solve your problem.

Check the [Elabel extension](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm) for google maps.